# What is the concordance model formulate for calculating the CMB temperature?

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background

Folks,
I am looking for the concordance model formula to calculate the temperature of the CMB for some time in the future.

I have seen the formula T0=2.7(1+z) the Einstein version or Concordance model?

I have also seen T(t) & a(t)^t  the symbol & is wrong, I could not find it on the keyboard.

Thanks
Nermo

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean $$T(t)=T_0(1+z)$$ and $$T(t)\propto \frac{1}{a(t)}= \frac{T_0}{a(t)}?$$ They are equivalent since $a(t)=1/(1+z)$.
These formulas give the temperature of the CMB, as it is redshifted by the expansion. They are not valid before recombination at z = 1100.

Comment: Hi,  Thank you for answering the question. Do you know if it can be used to calculate the temperature in the future?  Thanks Nermo

Comment: @2203312 - Yes, it should be valid in the future too.